# Polynomials to the 4th degree

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a, b, c$ and $ d$ are roots of $$2x^4-4x^3+6x^2+10x+12$$
Find $a^2, b^2, c^2 $ and $d^2$

I've tried using factors of the coefficients of the $4$th degree $(2)$ and the constant $(12)$ to solve with synthetic division and they all have me remainders.

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: @labbhattacharjee OP's work clearly uses RRT already...

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to display math in your mathSE queries.  You are new, so I did it for you, this time.

Comment: $$2x^4-4x^3+6x^2+10x+12 = 0$$
$$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$$
$$x^4-2x^3+3x^2+5x+6$$
$$x^4-(d+c+b+a)x^3+(cd+bd+ad+bc+ac+ab)x^2-(bcd+acd+abd+abc)x+abcd = 0$$
$$(x-a^2)(x-b^2)(x-c^2)(x-d^2)$$
This is a hint, expand this expression too and express the coefficient of the polynomial you are looking for in terms of the other

Comment: Re Aderinsola Joshua's hint, see also [Vieta's Formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas).

Comment: Are you sure the question doesn't want you to find the value of $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$? If we actually have to find the values of $a^2,b^2,c^2$ and $d^2$ that means solving a quartic with non-real roots... very ugly/time-consuming if we use the quartic formula.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee there are rational roots though.